# Should Java enum constants be retrieved through "get" methods or public final fields or both?

Tags: java, enums

See below code for example:

```
public enum Employees {  

    BOB("Bob Barker", "BB", 100);    

    private String fullName; //are these better accessed through public or getFullName() below? 
    private String initials;
    private String age;  

    Employees(String fullName, String initials, int age) {  
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.initials = initials;
        this.age = age;
    }  

    public String getFullName() {  
        return fullName;
    }  
    //etc ...
}
```

Which method of accessing more correct or more memory efficient?

Comment: Then it is not an enum...

Comment: @user1861310 you are misunderstanding enums, and more to the point that won't work

Comment: Good point, I deleted the setter method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access the `fullName` through a `static` method. They are *instance* fields.

Your code is correct. You may wish to mark your String fields as `final` and rid yourself of the `setXXX` methods (since `Enum` values are traditionally immutable).

Answer (score 3):

I would *always* make enum fields `final`, which then removes the utility of a setter. The `enum` instance is publicly shared and it is expected to be immutable by most sensible client code.

As far as the getter is concerned, that's up to your personal taste, although convention has it to add a getter and make the field private. So your taste has to be "strong".

Comment: using a getter is conventional

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Yes, but that convention is not necessarily related to enum types.

Comment: @NimChimpsky and convetional it's not "more memory efficient" in this case (enum)

Comment: @rcorbellini you are highlighting the extra stack memory required for the most basic getter ? Write it in assembler if you are that worried.

Comment: @rcorbellini: These things are likely to be optimised by the JVM at runtime. There's no real advantage in using `public` fields from a technical perspective. The question here is really whether to adhere to the convention or not, and NimChimpsky has a good point in his own answer (e.g. expression languages)

Answer (score 1):

use a getter its the convention ... and you won't get any nasty surprises if you at a later date use the enum within jstl/el which relies on the bean specification of using getters/is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of enums. An enum is a shared instance that does not change. What you describe is a regular mutable Java object. So the first thing you should do is switch from `enum` to `class`:

```
public class Employee {  

    private String fullName;
    private String initials;
    private String age;  

    public Employee(String fullName, String initials, int age) {  
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.initials = initials;
        this.age = age;
    }  

    public String getFullName() {  
        return fullName;
    }  
    //etc ...
}
```

Then use your class like a regular class:

```
Employee bob = new Employee("Bob Barker", "BB", 100);
```

**Edit**

You have removed your setter now, but still, this still does not look like an `enum` to me.

Comment: the setter is a no-no, but apart from that its a poje (I just invented that : plain-old-java-enum).

Comment: Maybe syntactically. But should it be? I do agree that the context has changed when the setter is removed, but from the original question, and the comments, it seems to me that this is something that might require mutable state eventually.

Comment: This whole enum vs class is a bit mind boggling. And figuring out the best way to go has been challenging to me.

Comment: @user1861310 An enum is for storing constants, they make it easy to create addtional functionality on the constant and ensure your code stays OOP and not coupled to magic numbers/strings.

Comment: @user1861310 To put it this way. What does your entity represent? An employee that always will be the same, never change, and is shared eveywhere it is needed? Or is it an employee that might change it's internal state, and maybe is fetched and initialized from somewhere else? Maybe what you're trying to represent is a `List` of `Employee`s?

Comment: @NilsH I think what you are saying is that I should save enums for objects that are very unchangeable, such as physics or days of the week, and things like employees, that are more likely to change values (names, ages, position, etc) should be put into classes.